# Looking for a fantasy trilogy and author; supposed to be based on real magical tales

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for a fantasy series that was probably written in the fifties to the late sixties.  I'm positive about most of the Author's name:  Peter (S.) Tibblet (?).  I know the last name began with T and there was a double letter -- almost certainly -bb- of my memory is correct.

The trilogy was somewhat more like three separated books with a common theme of one religion taking over from the last.  There was, in the third book, a Druid and his apprentice, who travelled to Britain/Avalon.  There the apprentice fell in love with one of the druid's equivalent priestess-in-training on the Isle, which was  Priestess-based Mother Goddess religion.

There were two ways of representing the same form.  In the Druid's case, it was a magic square.  However, if one took the lines of a magic square -- in the case of Mercury, that is the three-by-three magic square: 
| 4 9 2  |
| 3 5 7  |
| 8 1 6  |

If you took an ordinary square, numbered as your ordinary telephone keypad, and connected rows of dots, you got a representation of what the Goddess-based religion used: a V and an upside-down V with a diagonal line through both of them.  (This is also the sigil for Mercury and a lot of other gods of communication.)  Similarly with the 4-,5-,6-,7-, and 8- magic squares (though there was a "trick" to solving the Sun's square).  This thrilled the apprentice since it showed they were worshipping the same deities, though they had different representations of them.

At the end of the third book, the old Druid went to the astral equivalent of their Temple and changed the representation of the religion representing the Light to the symbol of the "white god's" new religion, the Cross.  Shortly afterwards, either barbarians or Romans invaded the temple and killed all of the priests and priestesses and all trainees and apprentices. But they were too late; the defenders of the Light was now Christianity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is the Seedbearers trilogy by Peter Valentine Timlett.

1. The Seedbearers
2. The Power of the Serpent
3. The Twilight of the Serpent

The basic plot matches:

http://sf-encyclopedia.uk/fe.php?nm=timlett_peter_valentine

> The Seedbearers (1974) is about the fall of Atlantis and the few who survive to pass the wisdom of the priests to the new world. It was followed by The Power of the Serpent (1976) and The Twilight of the Serpent (1977), the former about the building of Stonehenge, the latter about the conflict between the Culdees and the emergent Christian Church and the druids.

The magic also fits your description:

http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13517302-the-power-of-the-serpent

> It's as though we wouldn't appreciate the conflict between the Wessex and Druid cults without an understanding of the geometric basis of the Great Pyramid, or the numerological basis of Stonehenge, via the combination of magic squares and gematria and alchemy: "the basic spiritual equation is 1080 + 666 = 1746"...where sulphur (the positive dynamic principle) is 1080, mercury (the negative receptive principle) is 666, and gold (the highest whatever) is 1746.

Comment: This sounds exactly like the series I've been looking for.  Now that I have looked at those covers, I'm almost certain that this is the series.  Yes, an understanding of sacred geometry -- magic squares, gematria, and alchemy -- as the reviewer says, is not essential to the plot but is an interesting facet to the books.  

Now that I have read the review and seen the covers, details supporting the identification of these books as the series I was looking for is being dredged up from my subconscious at an extraordinary rate.